# Como pegar os valores de inputs e concatená-los Javascript

Tags: javascript

estou fazendo isto, mas não está funcionando

```
var nomeRua = document.getElementById('nomeRua').value();
var nomeBairro = document.getElementById('nomeBairro').value();
var uf = document.getElementById('uf').value();
var nomeCidade = document.getElementById('nomeCidade').value();
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': endereco + nomeRua + ", " + nomeBairro + ", " + uf + ", " + nomeCidade }, function (results, status) {

(...)
```

Comment: Usa só `.value;` e não `.value();`. Outra coisa, não vejo onde está o `endereco `?

Comment: Obrigada. O endereco está em outra parte

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O que procuras é o atributo `.value` e não um método como o `.val();` do jQuery ou `getValue();` de outras bibliotecas.

Mudando isso deve resolver. Já agora, uma sugestão para essa concatenação ficar mais legível::

```
var geoCode = [endereco + nomeRua, nomeBairro, uf, nomeCidade].join(', ');
geocoder.geocode({ 'address': geoCode }, function (results, status) {
```

Comment: ♦ Obrigada pela ajuda